# I am trying to fetch image from the database into the modal but the image is not showing in the modal

Tags: php, jquery, angular, database, image

Here is the code of the image i am trying to fetch

```
<img src="pics/file-upload-image-icon-115632290507ftgixivqp.png" id="image_preview1" class="img-thumbnail" style="margin-top: 15px; height:50%; width:20%">
```

Here is my code of the controller to fetch the data

```
$scope.fetch = function(sno) {
            $http.get("form-lab-full-json-fetch.php?sno="+sno).then(ok, notok);
            function ok(resp) {
                $scope.ARRY = resp.data;
            $scope.dept1 = $scope.ARRY[0].dept;
            $scope.uid1= $scope.ARRY[0].uid;
            $scope.uname1 = $scope.ARRY[0].uname;
            $scope.labname1 = $scope.ARRY[0].labname;
            $scope.labinfo1 = $scope.ARRY[0].labinfo;
                alert($scope.ARRY[0].orgname)
            $scope.hdn = $scope.ARRY[0].orgname;
                $scope.images1=$scope.ARRY[0].orgname;
                alert($scope.images1)
                **$scope.image_preview1.attr("src","uploads/"+ARRY[0].orgname);**
            }
                  function notok(resp) {
                alert(resp);
            }
        }
```

And here is the code of the preview file

```
 function preview_images1(file) {
    if (file.files && file.files[0])
     {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (ev) {
            $('#image_preview1').attr('src', ev.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wahts it´s your problem? in your controller, check in your query return your image:

```
$scope.image_preview1.attr("src","uploads/"+ARRY[0].orgname);
```

what return this?

when you check that retur this, you can return to your modal. You use frameworks or pur php? for return your image into modal, you can use AJAX and in response set in your tag `img` your `response.data.image`.

but first check that your code return your image, you can use

```
`print_r($scope.image_preview1.attr("src","uploads/"+ARRY[0].orgname))`
exit();
```